# Como colocar formato a un campo NUMBER desde SELECT

Tags: oracle, conversión-de-tipos, apex

Estoy trabajando en Oracle APEX una consulta para rellenar un grafico de tipo `PIE`necesito 4 campos para que se muestre el reporte, el QUERY utilizado es el siguiente:

```
SELECT "MENSAJE" ||': '|| TRIM("CANTIDAD") tool,
       "MENSAJE"  SeriesName,
       "CANTIDAD" Cantidad,
       "MENSAJE" LBL
FROM DASHBOARD_CLIENTES
WHERE "BASE_DATOS" = 'MASTER'
```

El campo `CANTIDAD` es de tipo  `NUMBER` necesito colocarle el formato 999,999,999 intente usar la función `TO_CHAR("CANTIDAD",'999,999,999')`  sin embargo no me permite utilizarlo debido a que APEX espera un dato de tipo numérico.

¿Hay alguna forma de colocarle el formato sin utilizar `to_char()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente el atributo VALUE recibe un campo de tipo numérico. Sin embargo, puede establecer el formato que requiere en los atributos del gráfico. (Seleccione el gráfico y en las propiedades, dirijase al tab Attributes).

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]